# Merging PHP arrays with different keys

Tags: php, arrays, merge, array-merge

I want to merge two arrays.

The first one looks like this:

```
 array(28) {
  [0]=>
  array(17) {
    ["category_id"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["image"]=>
    string(27) "718426050751.jpg"
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["top"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["column"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["sort_order"]=>
    string(2) "21"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["date_added"]=>
    string(19) "2015-07-30 14:06:42"
    ["date_modified"]=>
    string(19) "2016-01-05 12:21:32"
    ["language_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Faucets"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["meta_description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["meta_keyword"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["store_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["product_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["page_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
```

And the second one looks like this:

```
array(17) {
  ["category_id"]=>
  string(2) "13"
  ["image"]=>
  string(28) "4005176268779.jpg"
  ["parent_id"]=>
  string(2) "11"
  ["top"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["column"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["sort_order"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["status"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["date_added"]=>
  string(19) "2015-07-30 14:06:43"
  ["date_modified"]=>
  string(19) "2016-01-07 14:10:53"
  ["language_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name"]=>
  string(12) "Sink Faucets"
  ["description"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["meta_description"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["meta_keyword"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["store_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["product_count"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["page_count"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
```

As you can see the second one doesn't have a key like the first one does which is [0].

When I use:

```
$children = array_merge((array)$children, (array)$additional);
```

I get a merged array but the additional array is not getting a key which for me would preferably be [1] or +1 from the last array key.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming that $children is the first array, why not use $children[0] in your array merge? Something like `$children[0] = array_merge($children[0], $additional);`

Comment: Do you need array_merge? `$children[] = $additional` should work

Comment: do we need all this data to understaind your question ? can you keep it more simple ? otherwise you will loose many people who can help you :(

Comment: Gavin, that worked. Thanks! Can you post an answer so I can give you credit? Halayem, I can't ever post a question correctly on here. Either I give too much info or not enough. Everyone is so picky that I can;t make em all happy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [
    "0" => ["key1"=>"val1", "key2"=>"val2"]
    ];

$merge =  ["key1"=>"val3", "key2"=>"val4"];

array_merge($array, [$merge]);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key1] => val1
            [key2] => val2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key1] => val3
            [key2] => val4
        )

)
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a2e7abb2d9580b5f487d56b99a782505633c840b

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge()` is not necessary, you merely need to push the second array into the first. `$a[]=$b;` will add `$b`'s data to `$a` and assign an auto-incremented key without a function call.

Code:

```
$a=[
    0=>[
        "category_id"=>"11",
        "image"=>"718426050751.jpg",
        "parent_id"=>"1",
        "top"=>"0",
        "column"=>"1",
        "sort_order"=>"21",
        "status"=>"1",
        "date_added"=>"2015-07-30 14:06:42",
        "date_modified"=>"2016-01-05 12:21:32",
        "language_id"=>"1",
        "name"=>"Faucets",
        "description"=>"",
        "meta_description"=>"",
        "meta_keyword"=>"",
        "store_id"=>"1",
        "product_count"=>"0",
        "page_count"=>"0"
    ]
];
$b=[
    "category_id"=>"13",
    "image"=>"4005176268779.jpg",
    "parent_id"=>"11",
    "top"=>"0",
    "column"=>"1",
    "sort_order"=>"2",
    "status"=>"1",
    "date_added"=>"2015-07-30 14:06:43",
    "date_modified"=>"2016-01-07 14:10:53",
    "language_id"=>"1",
    "name"=>"Sink Faucets",
    "description"=>"",
    "meta_description"=>"",
    "meta_keyword"=>"",
    "store_id"=>"1",
    "product_count"=>"0",
    "page_count"=>"0"
];
$a[]=$b;  // push, not merge
var_export($a);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'category_id' => '11',
    'image' => '718426050751.jpg',
    'parent_id' => '1',
    'top' => '0',
    'column' => '1',
    'sort_order' => '21',
    'status' => '1',
    'date_added' => '2015-07-30 14:06:42',
    'date_modified' => '2016-01-05 12:21:32',
    'language_id' => '1',
    'name' => 'Faucets',
    'description' => '',
    'meta_description' => '',
    'meta_keyword' => '',
    'store_id' => '1',
    'product_count' => '0',
    'page_count' => '0',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'category_id' => '13',
    'image' => '4005176268779.jpg',
    'parent_id' => '11',
    'top' => '0',
    'column' => '1',
    'sort_order' => '2',
    'status' => '1',
    'date_added' => '2015-07-30 14:06:43',
    'date_modified' => '2016-01-07 14:10:53',
    'language_id' => '1',
    'name' => 'Sink Faucets',
    'description' => '',
    'meta_description' => '',
    'meta_keyword' => '',
    'store_id' => '1',
    'product_count' => '0',
    'page_count' => '0',
  ),
)
```

Comment: @smack-a-bro Your question appeared to be abandoned and this represents a dead-end for future SO researchers.  Since Gavin did not post an answer for you to accept, I've posted something so that your question can have closure.